# Why does 2 scroll bars appear on my page? 1 inner scroll bar and 1 outer scroll bar?

Tags: css, scroll, parallax, jquery-ias

Why does 2 scroll bars appear on my page? 1 inner scroll bar and 1 outer scroll bar?

I am using infinite ajax scroll here: http://infiniteajaxscroll.com

and pure css parallax scrolling here: http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Here is my demo: http://bycustomdesign.com/_misc/_09/page1.html

Page 1 generates 2 scroll bars, inner and outer. I don't know why. **How do I get rid of inner scroll bar but still able to scroll down to page 2 and page 3.**

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following CSS to the inner scrolling div may help:

```css
inner { 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not help. Inner div now can not parallax: http://bycustomdesign.com/_misc/_09/page1b.html

Answer (score 1):

You also can use in case something else is causing this

```
html {
  overflow-x: initial !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a wrapper around my parallax div.

By reducing the height of the wrapper, the second scrollbar is now gone.
So try reducing the height of the div around your parallax div.

```
wrapper {
  height: 650px;
}
```